# Azure storage account queue get new messages arrived (Ideally Logic App)

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to design a logic app where when a message arrives or is received by poison queue(located in azure storage account) it posts to slack channel.

I know how to do the slack part and I can get the trigger to fire on queues located in my service bus resource because azure logic apps includes triggers for that.

However, I don't see azure logic app triggers for queues in the storage account for when a message arrives or is received in a queue.

My question is: Is there a trigger or other process that I can tap into when messages arrives in those storage account queues? If not, what is the best way to achieve being able to get this data (Message and Message Content) when it arrives in my poison queue in the storage account then take that info and throw that info into the slack channel?

Is there a trigger (for logic app) on the “storage account” queues that can be fired when a message is received?(I see length, and scan all messages in queue)

I have found triggers for this on the “service bus” queues.

These are the trigger options I have found for "service bus queues": https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS0nu.png

These are the trigger options I have found for "storage account queues": https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqxB4.png

Ideally, I just want to configure a simple logic app for when queue messages arrive in poison queue in storage account then take info to slack, i know how to put info in slack via logic app in service bus queue but haven't been able to figure out how to set up the action to pass the message to slack because I can't figure out how to do it when a message is recieved, i can set it as a job and grab length of queue and all items in queue, but not fire on arrival because I can't find a trigger for that.

If I can't figure this out or if at can't be done, I am probably just going to initiate the logic app with and Azure Queue storage trigger on an Azure function, this seems to be how MS wants us to do it anyway.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to
ctrl+f "Binding reference information" then see sub heading "Usage:  The types you can bind to and information about how the binding works. For example: polling algorithm, poison queue processing."

thanks again for the input folks, appreciate ya!

Answer (score 1):

According to some test, it works fine in my side with "[When a specified number of messages are in a given queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azurequeues/#when-a-specified-number-of-messages-are-in-a-given-queue)" trigger. When I add a message to my queue which named `myqueue-items-poison`, the logic app was triggered success.

So please check if you have configured the trigger correctly.
[image]

Please check if you set the interval of the trigger too long, I set it with 1 minute.

Comment: Trying to do the same things but dont see any triggers for Azure Queue in Logic apps. 
 Basically trying to invoke the logic app workflow if message recieved in a Azure Queue.  Any help is appreciated .